# NAS with off-site vault subscription?

Tags: network-attached-storage, backup

We have some small clients (clinics, doctor's offices, law firms, etc.) with a handful of machines who's only need is shared network storage.  Mostly when we come in we find that there's some machine that's running XP Home with a share, sometimes there's a USB drive for backup, most of the time there's no automation (or the machine's turned off at night) so it's not consistent.

For our larger clients and off-site colos, we've been using Barracuda's Backup Server with the off-site backup service and that works great, but what would be perfect is a small RAID-enabled NAS unit that also includes an optional off-site backup subscription.

I guess I could build a mini-ITX system running Samba and rsync to some off-site backup service, but an all-in-one turnkey solution from a reputable vendor would be preferable.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

QNAP NAS devices can do this. www.qnap.com

Answer (score 0):

If you build your own with your own off-site servers for backups, you can charge your clients less and have a better profit margin.

This would not be a complicated device and you could potentially use [FreeNAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeNAS) or [Openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/).  The only cost is your time, which you can bill.  The backup servers could be a subscription basis.